# python Can't change start video

Tags: python

I want to change opening the link by typing yes or no.
but I tryt everything whithout succes

```
input3 = input ("3. " + input_name + " ik heb een liedje wil je hem horen: ")
import webbrowser
if ("input_3 = ja")
webbrowser.open (' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLaOsNwmieE ')
```

Comment: `if (input_3 == "ja")`

Comment: @MarounMaroun - then you also need a colon and an indent...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
input3 = input ("3. " + input_name + " ik heb een liedje wil je hem horen: ")
import webbrowser
if input_3 == "ja":
    webbrowser.open (' https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLaOsNwmieE ')
```

Your input returns a string, so your indent was wrong. Correct one is `==` not `=`, also if you wrote it like `"input3"` Python will see that a regular string. But it's a variable that you defined and you don't need parantheses.

```
"input_3 == ja" #this is a regular string like "Hello"
 input_3 == "ja" #this checks the condition. If input_3 equals to 'ja'.
```

Quotes changes everything, remember that `"4"` is different than `4`.